# Firebase Cloud Function schedule to create document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We have a Flutter project with Firebase setup we would like to create a
Firebase cloud function with node js that perform the following:

Every 27th of any month check the subscription date from the subscription collection. And create a new document in invoices collection then finally send an email & FCM with a payment URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to use a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

More precisely, you need to:

- [Schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function) the Cloud Function as desired, for example with `0 0 27 * *`, i.e. at 00:00 on day-of-month 27.
- In the Cloud Function, query your Firestore collection for "checking the subscription dates"
- In the Cloud Function, send an email. For example through the [Trigger Email extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email). it's actually just a matter of creating a doc in a Firestore collection, see this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-send-e-mails-using-firebase-extensions-a10d7cd685c2) for more details.
- In the Cloud Function, send the FCM as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) in the doc.

---

For the last 3 points, you need to use the Admin SDKs since you are coding in a Cloud Function. ([Doc for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.firestore) and [doc for Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging))